# add cname to grunt file

Tags: github, gruntjs, yeoman, cname

I'm using yeoman to scaffold my site, and i need to add a cname file to my dist directory, so that I can set up a custom domain for my gh-pages branch.

whenisournextgame.com - http://mattbtay.github.io/whenisournextgame

I currently manually added the file, I would like to see this as part of the build process, when I make changes to the site, and a new dist directory is created it will end up getting deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the original as part of your `src` folder, and use [grunt-contrib-copy](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) to copy it to your `dist` folder.